# Compiler tells me I am not expanding my parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I am getting a compiler error for this simple variadic template function:

*error C3520: 'StringType': parameter pack must be expanded in this context*

The error message is clear but unexpected.

```
template<class... StringType>
void CopySomethingOrOther(const std::wstring& destination, const StringType& ... files)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(files))
        (CopyAcrossFile(files, destination), ...);
}
```

This function takes a destination string and a variadic number of file paths and it copies each file into the destination directory. The error points to the line of the function head, but I am not sure if this is of any significance.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Did you enable C++17 support in it?

Comment: What line the error happens on?

Comment: Included code [works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SXniQe99DxqX3m90). Looks like problem is in `CopyAcrossFile` and how `CopySomethingOrOther` is used (wrong types of arguments).

Comment: Unrelated, but the `if constexpr` isn't necessary here. When `files` is empty, the fold-expression just becomes `void()`.